# How to convert a data matrix into a relational table using Google Sheets formula - follow up question

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, transpose

This is a follow up question to:
[How to convert a data matrix into a relational table using Google Sheets formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743190/how-to-convert-a-data-matrix-into-a-relational-table-using-google-sheets-formula)

The formula from player() works great.

I'm having problem in doing this for a large data set. I created a sample data set 32 columns and 198 rows. I am getting "Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."
Here is the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19176EF9luKQjmmVNxdC3CwF4Qqtwrz-Ux4mtxZujuF0/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I put the formula in Sheet2!A1.
I changed Sheet1!B2:Z to Sheet1!B2:AF to match the matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Trim function will not work with more 50000 chars.

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Country", "Date", "Value"; SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( IF(Sheet1!B2:Z<>"","♠"&Sheet1!A2:A&"♦"&Sheet1!B1:1&"♦"&Sheet1!B2:Z,)),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 2, 1, 1, 1)})
```

Comment: This is excellent. I am going to now try it on my live data.

Comment: It worked great on the live data! Thanks!